# Website in Tableau Web Page Object not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tableau-api, qtwebkit

So I've developed a simple website consisting of a login page and a 'control panel' which I'm embedding in Tableau Desktop using the Web Page object.

I'm having a few issues with the site working/rendering differently in the Web Page object vs my Chrome browser, the major one being the login button isn't working.

When a user clicks the login button, I validate their username and password against a database and if they are indeed correct I use `window.open ('xxxxxxxxx.html','_self',false)` to open the 'control panel' page. If the username and password are incorrect then I display an `alert()`.

I know that clicking the login button is at least executing the POST request because if the username and password are incorrect the alert displays. If they are correct however, nothing happens. `window.open ('xxxxxxxxx.html','_self',false)` seems to be the weak link.

I've read that the Tableau Web Page object is powered by QTWebKit so I'm assuming it's a compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct, window.open is unfortunately not supported Tableau's current implementation.  I would encourage you to just redirect the user to a new page that can serve as the control panel, or build the control panel widget into the existing page.